# Обязательный ввод кода/стектрейса ошибки

Tags: обсуждение, вопросы

Многие люди не указывают в вопросе стектрейс ошибки. Так же попадаются те, кто воспринял сообщество как форум для обязательной помощи, сами не пытаются ничего сделать, задают вопрос и все, его закрывают.

Что-то надо придумать

Comment: Вы предлагаете завести для этого отдельное поле ввода? А если вопрос не связан с ошибкой? Как написать такой интеллектуальный анализатор вопроса, чтобы он однозначно определял нужен ли здесь код ошибки или нет?

Comment: @Андрей NOP, Скорее всего завести фильтр по словам типа "Вылетает" в заголовке и/или описании вопроса. Или сделать выбор типа вопроса "how-to" и "ошибка" и т.д. Или хотя бы добавить возможность отметить вопрос как "Требует кода", " Требует сообщения ошибки"

Comment: Проблема понятная и острая - поэтому согласен. Однако понимаю минусующих: все инструменты уже есть, а каких-то прорывных вариантов решения не видно. Оформил ответом своё видение.

Comment: Стектрейс делать обязательным категорически нельзя, потому что: (1) исключения не везде есть как понятие, (2) не любые ошибки заявляют о себе исключениями.

Answer (score 7):

Ничего не нужно дополнительно придумывать, все инструменты уже есть:

- Можно оставить комментарий под вопросом с просьбой автору предоставить код / стектрейс или что ещё потребуется
- Можно проголосовать за закрытие вопроса, там даже причина уже готовая есть "Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе"
- Можно поставить минус (пользуюсь редко, в основном предпочитаю закрыть вопрос)

Я не думаю, что выбор типа вопроса "требуются телепаты", "я новичок ничё не понимаю" и "я лентяй" это полезное решение.

Аналогично заводить какие-то фильтры, ботов – всё это слишком зыбко и неточно. Человек – лучшая мера всех вещей. Прочитал, прокомментировал, проголосовал за закрытие вопроса.

Comment: обязательный ввод конечно не подходит, но "либо либо" не всегда конструктивно. Лучше "и и": **и** люди с комментариями, кнопками править/закрыть **и** боты, которые автоматически вопрос в очередь проверок засунут или к примеру *подсказки*, более фокусированные могут показывать (в зависимости от содержимого, действий на сайте) или предложить чат с ментором начать, чтобы довести вопрос синхронно до терпимого состояния или наоборот сразу указать, что не подойдёт вопрос, можно время не тратить.